# PHP method to hide link until user logged in

Tags: php, html

I used this to hide links until after the user is logged in, and was just wondering if this will cause any security issues or other issues in production code? I have been testing it and cannot find an issue so far as the website will not give a session_id until after the user logs on.

```
if(session_id()){echo '<a href="./ewo.php" target="_self"> EWO </a>'...
```

Comment: If the same check is done inside `ewo.php` then I shouldn't see why it wouldn't work. If it's not done, then anyone who knows the URL to it, will have access to it. Username and password checking would also be an added bonus, along with a token.

Comment: The existence of a session will  not be a guarantee that the user will actually be logged in, is it? Why not simply use the "is logged in" function of whatever library you are using?

Comment: There is no "is logged in" function as of yet; I am not using a "whatever library", it is my own code and database. It is not a customer facing website only internal and there is code to kill the session and redirect should UID or IP change. If a non user navigates to the page it will not load, and if the user navigates to the URL the page will not load unless they are logged in and the session is valid.

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem in this code until you put a session check also in the file

if session id is not set then send them back to home page.. Because if user knows the URL then they can navigate to the link

Comment: But the user wants to know  whether the user is logged in, not whether a session exists.

Comment: As @Pekka웃 said, plus there isn't really an answer that applies here. The OP obviously already has code, and just wants to know if it will cause any security issues. Unless you have substantial code to offer the OP, this does not qualify as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to add a function which will redirect the users to the login page as soon as the session gets destroyed i.e logout.

Also, as mentioned by @Saeed Ansari, add some logic to your project so only the login page is rendered when there is no active session or the user is not logged in.

HTH.

Comment: The existence of a session should never be used as an indicator whether a user is logged in or not. The code the OP is showing is broken. An answer should address that to be considered a good answer.

Comment: [Same comment applies](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19642692/php-method-to-hide-link-until-user-logged-in#comment29165608_19642845)

Answer (score 0):

Either way, if your solution is to simply 'hide this link' until the user has logged in, this is not constructive code.

You *should* have a user object or user $_SESSION identifier registered in the session for when the user logs on.

For example.  User logs on, you set a flag $_SESSION['Username'] = "Bob", where Bob is the user's username.

Then in your code, you could do something along the lines of:

```
if(array_key_exists('Username', $_SESSION)) { echo '<a href="./ewo.php" target="_self"> EWO </a>'; }
```

Then when a user logs into your site successfully, register their username (atleast) in the $_SESSION, ie

```
$_SESSION['Username'] = 'Bob';
```

It is a good idea to have full control over your session by using session variables, rather than just relying on if a session has an ID.

It is never safe to assume, so I would also recommend (if you haven't done so) checking in the ewo.php file for the same thing ... check if the session has a registered Username/etc and if not redirect `header('Location: /');` for example, to redirect the user back to the home page.

Comment: This `header('Location /');` in invalid. Show something to the affect of `header('Location: http://www.example.com/');` - Not having the colon in there will trigger an error.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it via a Session.

If you wanna check if the variable is set (User is logged in) in the session use:

```
<?php
session_start();


if (isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
   echo "Your link here";
} else {
   echo "login first";
}
?>
```