# hide link in forum until user comment

Tags: javascript, html, css

i want to make a simple code, using HTML CSS Javascipt, that will allow only registered members who left at least one comment to see a specific part of the post. i can't use php or such, cause it's on a forum, and we're only allowed to add on our own only simple scripts. the forum usually use bbcode to create posts and such but we can also write posts using html

i already know the script to hide a part of a post to non-registered memeber, but i want one to make it visible to only member who left a comment

it's like the qusetion= [PHP method to hide link until user logged in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19642692/php-method-to-hide-link-until-user-logged-in)

we have this script for Register here to view links and images

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://nb.forumfree.it/scripts/ace/link_guests.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
msgRegLink = "Registrati qui per visualizzare i link e le immagini";
selectSez = ["all","12345"];
hideIMG= false;
</script>
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit how the data comes from the server, is it an array, an object... array of objects. Will be able to help you out.

Comment: we don't know because we are not the owner of the site

Answer (score 0):

You could use a flag to achieve this. Give the div to be conditionally shown in an if condition. Initially set it as false, change it to true once the user clicks the comment button. I have generally summarised the code below as I have not seen your code

isShown: false

When the user clicks the comment button, maybe call a function commented()

```
commented() {
   if (isShown == false) {
    isShown: true
   }
}
```

Comment: Yea, I just gave you the idea